# Compile Error: Else without If Vb6

Tags: vb6

Un proyecto bastante antiguo tengo que quitar los descuentos de una sucursal ... pero al agregar el código (que es exactamente igual a los demás solo con una condición si un lblSucursal es X pasa ahi..

Queda constar que este lenguaje casi no lo conocí..

'Si la sucursal es San Lorenzo quita los descuentos

```
        If lblSucursal.Caption = "SAN LORENZO" Then
            .Open "SELECT * FROM CATALOGO_DescuentosParaArticulosOrdinariosGeneral WHERE Id ='2' ORDER BY MinimoEnUnidades DESC", cnnPv, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
                Do While Not .EOF
                    m_PrecioFinal = Art(ArtAct).PrecioSinIva - (Art(ArtAct).PrecioSinIva * (Val(NoNull(.Fields("Descuento").Value, "0")) / 100))
                    If Val(NoNull(.Fields("MinimoEnUnidades"), "0")) <= Art(ArtAct).cantidad And Val(NoNull(.Fields("MinimoEnDinero"), "0")) <= Art(ArtAct).cantidad * m_PrecioFinal Then ' Art(ArtAct).PUnitario Then
                        If Art(ArtAct).costo > 0 Then
                            m_PorcentajeDeDiferencia = ((m_PrecioFinal / Art(ArtAct).costo) - 1) * 100
                            If m_PorcentajeDeDiferencia >= m_PorcentajeMinimoDeUtilidad Then
                                Art(ArtAct).DescPorTabla = Val(NoNull(.Fields("Descuento"), "0")) / 100
                                LblDescto(RengAct).Caption = Format(Art(ArtAct).DescPorTabla * 100, "#0.0")
                                Exit Do
                            End If
                        Else
                            Art(ArtAct).DescPorTabla = Val(NoNull(.Fields("Descuento").Value, "0")) / 100
                            LblDescto(RengAct).Caption = Format(Art(ArtAct).DescPorTabla * 100, "#0.0")
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    End If
                    .MoveNext
                Loop
                If .State <> adStateClosed Then .Close 
            End If
         Else
                'Si no sigue con los descuentos normales
                .Open "SELECT * FROM CATALOGO_DescuentosParaArticulosOrdinariosGeneral ORDER BY MinimoEnUnidades DESC", cnnPv, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
                Do While Not .EOF
                    m_PrecioFinal = Art(ArtAct).PrecioSinIva - (Art(ArtAct).PrecioSinIva * (Val(NoNull(.Fields("Descuento").Value, "0")) / 100))
                    If Val(NoNull(.Fields("MinimoEnUnidades"), "0")) <= Art(ArtAct).cantidad And Val(NoNull(.Fields("MinimoEnDinero"), "0")) <= Art(ArtAct).cantidad * m_PrecioFinal Then ' Art(ArtAct).PUnitario Then
                        If Art(ArtAct).costo > 0 Then
                            m_PorcentajeDeDiferencia = ((m_PrecioFinal / Art(ArtAct).costo) - 1) * 100
                            If m_PorcentajeDeDiferencia >= m_PorcentajeMinimoDeUtilidad Then
                                Art(ArtAct).DescPorTabla = Val(NoNull(.Fields("Descuento"), "0")) / 100
                                LblDescto(RengAct).Caption = Format(Art(ArtAct).DescPorTabla * 100, "#0.0")
                                Exit Do
                            End If
                        Else
                            Art(ArtAct).DescPorTabla = Val(NoNull(.Fields("Descuento").Value, "0")) / 100
                            LblDescto(RengAct).Caption = Format(Art(ArtAct).DescPorTabla * 100, "#0.0")
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    End If
                    .MoveNext
                Loop
                If .State <> adStateClosed Then .Close
        End If ' DE METREABLE
End If       ' DE CONTINUA BUSCANDO
End With
```

On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Sub

```
DeterminaTipoDeDescuento2_Error:

    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure DeterminaTipoDeDescuento2 of Formulario Form_PV"
    SendErr "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure DeterminaTipoDeDescuento2 of Formulario Form_PV"
End Sub
```

Es la parte del codigo encargada de calcular el descuento del PV pero actualmente esta con las condiciones adecuadas...

Comment: Trate de arreglar tu codigo pero es muy dificil porque te falto un pedazo. Mas alla de eso, el compilador te debe estar diciendo que linea es la que genera el error.

Comment: @gbianchi subire el codigo completo en un txt a un servidor publico ... porque si es un pedazo grande pero el error solo me dice el error que puse como titulo :/ 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z12iwBFLVjz0wgKd2vQTULtCBXIga1CQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Tu codigo debe estar en la pregunta. Nadie va a entrar a un servidor a verlo. Y si es mucho, te recomiendo que empieces a revisar. Por que el error es claro... falta un if o sobra un else... y si acomodas tu codigo se deberia notar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes

```
[snip]
               Loop
                If .State <> adStateClosed Then .Close 
            End If
else
[snip]
```

Cuando el parte despues del "Then" aparece en la misma linea como el "if", termina el "if." (Es decir, el fin de la linea termina el "if", no el "end if".)  Significa el siguiente "End If" pertenece al primer "If", o mejor dicho

```
If lblSucursal.Caption = "SAN LORENZO" Then
```

Entonces, el "else" no pertence a nada.

Si escribe

```
If .State <> adStateClosed then
    .Close
End If
```

tambien resuelva el problema.

Semejante, tiene el mismo problema en el fondo del código.

Comment: wow.. bien visto..

Comment: Realmente funciono ... solo agregue unos cambios y listo sin problema, muchísimas gracias!